# Apply an operation to all value in the list

Tags: python

The value in my list are delta of days comparing with the starting date. I need to convert them to date format (in YYYYDD). I was using following code:

```
import datetime
date = "20180330"
y = int(date[0:4])
m = int(date[4:6])
d = int(date[6:8])
starting_date = datetime.date(y, m, d)
tanor = map(lambda x: starting_date + datetime.timedelta(days=int(x))
```

This seems not working.

Comment: What is your Python version: in 3.x `map` returns an iterator. In addition, how have you defined `DT`?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for the `map()` function (type `help(map)` into the Python interpreter). You need to apply your function to some data: `map(func, *iterables)`

Comment: "This seems not working." How so? Do you get an error? Does the result not meet your expectations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
import datetime

date = "20180330"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y%m%d")

list_of_days = [1,2,3]

l = [(date + datetime.timedelta(days=d)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for d in list_of_days]
print(l)
```

Output

```
['2018-03-31', '2018-04-01', '2018-04-02']
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working perfectly. Actually I have an additional question. If it's possible to make the starting date in YYYY-MM format. and then I make my list as the difference of months. And in the end calculate the date (in YYYYMM format) for each element of the list.

Comment: yes.. same way, only replace days with months (dont forget to use minus for difference) as well as change the format from "%Y%m%d" to "%Y%m" for only year and month

Comment: `date = "201803"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y%m")`  I ran this code, it will return "2018-03-01 00:00:00" instead of "2018-03".

Answer (score 2):

This might help you:

```
import datetime
date = "20180330"
dates = ["20180330","20180430","20160130"]
# Timestamp
datesConverted = map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x),dates)
print(list(datesConverted))
# Datetime
datesConverted = map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).date(),dates)
print(list(datesConverted))
```

I convert your list of **strings** to a list of **datetimes** or **timestamps**

Answer (score 2):

```
tanor = map(lambda x: starting_date + DT.timedelta(days=int(x))
```

You are passing nothing to the `map`, i.e.: you are not giving it the list of deltas.

Take into account that if you are using Python 3.x, `map` will not immediately apply the operation. You will have to either iterate over the result or pass it to a list.

So:

```
tanor = list(map(lambda x: starting_date + DT.timedelta(days=int(x)), my_deltas))
```